# How can I consolidate different heating/cooling systems into a single system?

Tags: heating, thermostat, home-automation, cooling

I have 3 different types of heating/cooling systems that I inherited.

1. Hot water heat. This heats the whole house/garage via 3 zones.

   - Zone 1: Kitchen/Livingroom
   - Zone 2: Bedrooms/Bath
   - Zone 3: Garage
2. In Floor Heating

   - Zone 1: Kitchen
   - Zone 2: Hallway
   - Zone 3: Bathroom
3. Forced Air AC

   - Only one zone/thermostat

What I am looking for is to consolidate all these thermostats into one "system".

Comment: Are you looking to control on/off and temperature from one location but still maintain independent zones/temperature sensors so they could kick off independent of each other, basically a Master-Slave scenario? Quite a few commercial solutions exists, residential I'd look for the items termed home-automation.

Comment: You could probably configure a unified controller using gear from [Easy IO](http://www.easyio.com/).  I haven't used that brand myself (but have come close), but it has been recommended to me by an industrial HVAC engineer as "can control anything, easy to program, and reasonably priced."

Answer (score -1):

With the [ODControl](http://www.opendomo.com/products/ODControl) from [OpenDomo](http://www.opendomo.com/) You can control up to 8 on/off outputs, 8 on/off inputs and (with the complementary module) up to 8 analog sensors. Is designed so you can configure it for any automation, and you can control it from a smartphone or tablet. In your case, each line will be controlling one zone or another.

Disclosure: Responder works for this company.

Comment: Promotion of specific products is frowned upon by the community, especially when all of your answers are promoting the same product. See [What kind of behavior is expected of users](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Chris. BTW, I want to mention that the system is based in opensource, and the communication protocols are open, so it makes it very suitable for integration.

Comment: @BMitch My speciality (vocational and professional) is home automation. I will answer all the questions related to it with my knowledge, which happens to be related to this open technology. It's a fact.

Comment: I clearly stated in the answer my relation with this product. Further editions have been softening this statement, so is not in my hands anymore. I'd be glad that, at least the editors could upvote the answer to compensate downvotes...

Comment: "If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons." Their words, but don't be surprised if the community enforces them.

Comment: True. Probably I should enter in discussions about hammering a nail.